# How to display Command output in real time in Symfony 3.4 when calling from a Controller?

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4, symfony-console

I have some commands in a Symfony 3.4 application that I call, from my controller: what I want to achieve is to get their output real-time and print it on the screen.

I tried almost everything about Symfony processes, as per their documentation, but nothing worked: I always get an empty output (if I dump the content it gives me an empty string).

My Command:

```
class TestCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('say:hello');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
            $output->writeln(str_pad("$i: Hello Ale", 4096));

            sleep(1);
        }
    }
}
```

My Controller:

```
    /**
     * @Route("/test")
     */
    public function testRoute() {
        $process = new Process(['cd', '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MyTestProject/', '&&', 'php bin/console say:hello']);
        $process->start();
        while($process->isRunning()) {
            dump($process->getIncrementalOutput());
        }

        die();
    }
```

The dumped output:
[image: Dumped content]

Comment: Have you tried with `echo $process->getIncrementalOutput();`?

Comment: Yes, I did, but nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

In controller try using:

```
 $process = new Process('php /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MyTestProject/bin/console say:hello');

 $process->run(function ($type, $buffer) {
    echo $buffer
 });
```

See [Getting real-time Process Output](https://symfony.com/doc/master/components/process.html#getting-real-time-process-output)

Comment: Yes, lots of time! Nothing happened :(

Comment: No error: but I want to edit my previous answer: I actually get an output, but all the output is printed at the end of the execution, not in realtime

Comment: Try to add this after execution of process
if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
    throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
}

echo $process->getOutput();

Comment: What OS / Environment do you use?